# Major Support on a login script

Tags: php, session, cookies, authentication

Whenever I change pages to like blog or forum it looses the session. I then click login and it has the session so its says your already logged in.Support?
---> http://www.kdogisthebest.webege.com/

username: demouser

password: demouser

login.php

```
<?php session_start();  require_once('connections/Main.php');

if($_SESSION['username']) {

    echo '<div class="error_message">Attention! You, '.$_SESSION['username'].' are already logged in.</div>';   echo "<br />";  echo "Go <a target='top' href='index.php'>back</a> to the page you were viewing before this.</li>";     
exit(); }
```

.../// Skipped database check ///...

```
// Check that at least one row was returned 
    $rowCheck = mysql_num_rows($result); 

    if($rowCheck > 0) { 
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

      // Start the session and register a variable 
      if(isset($_POST['remmemberme'])){
          setcookie(kitbusername, $uesr, time()*24);
      }
      $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
      //session_register('username'); 

      echo '<script> parent.document.location.href = "index.php"; </script>';

      } ?>
```

logout.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
// unset cookies
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
        $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
if($_SESSION['username']) {
session_unset(); 
session_destroy(); 
header("Location: index.php"); } 
else { header("Location: index.php"); } ?>
```

header.php

```
<div id="loginoutbox" class="ablack">
```

```
<div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 20px;">Hello <?php  if($_COOKIE['kitbusername']) { echo $_COOKIE['kitbusername'];} else {echo $_SESSION['username'];} ?>! | </div>
<a id="register" href="http://www.kdogisthebest.webege.com/admin/" class="button">Dashboard</a> |
<a id="signin" href="#fallr-confirmlike" class="button">Logout</a>      
<?php }else{ ?>
<div style="display: inline-block; font-size: 14px; padding-left: 20px;">Hello Guest!</div>
<a id="register" href="#fallr-register" class="button">Register</a> |
<a id="signin" href="#fallr-signin" class="button">Login</a>
<?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show what part of the code accesses the logout.php file? I think I may have found something but I need to know how logout.php is accessed before I know for sure.

Comment: yea its in the header Ill edit it

Comment: its actualy a modal drop down script I have that shows the logout.php in an iframe like on www.fallr.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the variable $user is misspelled as $uesr in the setcookie function. If that was not your intention, that could possibly be the problem.

Comment: that didnt work because the user variable would be set equal to the session variable. The way I had it, it logs in but when you change pages the session variable doesnt transfer over but when you click ligin it says Im already logged in and shows the session

Comment: I think I found your problem.

Comment: do you think it could be the <script> parent.document.location.href = "index.php"; </script>

Comment: Possibly, explain what your trying to do there.

Comment: redirect the iframe's parent to the index.php